# PhpStorm global search not working

Tags: phpstorm

In the last two weeks, and for reasons unknown to me, PhpStorm has stopped finding strings in project searches (although I know they are there). I have the latest version of PhpStorm installed.

`Ctrl + Shift + F` goes through the motions but returns nothing.

Does anybody else have this problem and a solution?

Comment: Try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- should help in such "suddenly stopped working" situations.

Comment: Hey @LazyOne, awesome, it worked. Please add as answer so I can upvote. Saved me a lot of pain.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please use `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- it usually helps in such "suddenly stopped working" situations (similar to "reboot your PC" solution).

The reason is that some indexes got broken or out of sync for some reason .. and this action just marks all caches and indexes as "invalid/damaged" so IDE will discard them on next launch (you can check `idea.log` for exact wording).

Please note that this will also discard your Local History in case you are using it.